# Firebase cloud function url is not the base url for requests from the frontend

Tags: node.js, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, axios

I'm building a web application with ReactJS on the front end and using Node and Express with Firestore to retrieve data from the backend.

I am using axios for the HTTP requests. I have set the baseurl using `axios.default.baseURL = "https://us-central1-<project-id>.cloudfunctions.net/api"`. That is the end point for all of my cloud functions. These functions include get/post that retrieve or update some data that is stored in Firestore.

They are all exported as one function using express: `exports.api = functions.https.onRequest(app);`

My firebase.json rewrites is as follows:

```
"hosting": {
    "public": "build",
    "ignore": ["firebase.json", "**/.*", "**/node_modules/**"],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "function": "api"
      }
    ]
  }
```

The problem is, on my deployed site, some axios http calls go to the proper baseUrl that I had set as the default. Others go to my host url: `<project-id>.firebaseapp.com/getData`.

Is there something that I am not doing correctly? I want all of the http requests to go to the proper base url, but I cannot seem to get it to work.

Comment: Please edit the question to show the code you're using, as well as the HTTP requests that do an do not route the way you expect.  As your question stands right now, it's difficult to tell exactly what is not working the way you expect.  We should be able to reproduce the exact behavior based on what you provide in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your hosting configuration, the base URL for calls to your API should be `<project-id>.firebaseapp.com/`. If you wanted to access your Cloud Function's `/getData` express route, you would make the request to `<project-id>.firebaseapp.com/getData`.

In general, you try to avoid calling the `cloudfunctions.net` domain directly but also be wary that placing your Cloud Function behind Firebase Hosting also introduces a CDN into the pipeline. The CDN will cache results and invoke your Cloud Function whilst discarding cookies that aren't `__session`.

To prevent unneccessarily passing all requests to your Cloud Function, I would change your configuration so that your Cloud Function is only invoked on the path `/api`.

```
"hosting": {
  "public": "build",
  "ignore": ["firebase.json", "**/.*", "**/node_modules/**"],
  "rewrites": [
    {
      "source": "api/**",
      "function": "api"
    }
  ]
}
```

which will require changing your express routes to `/api/getData`, etc.